# Why using constant expression as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

When it is better to have a private data member (`_val` in `class B`) and when it is better to have `val` as a template parameter (`class A`)?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int val>
class A{
public:
        A(){ cout << val << endl;}
};

class B{
public:
        B(int val) : _val(val) { cout << val << endl;}
private:
        int _val;
};

int main()
{
        A<7> a;
        B b(8);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the value during runtime? Then you have your answer there.

Comment: @chuck No. Templates are a compile-time construct.

Comment: @chuck, how to change `val` from 7 to 8 after creating object `A<7> a` ?

Comment: @cpp you can't change the template argument, it is a fixed property of a class.

Comment: These are entirely different cases. A class template with a non-type parameter will create a new type for each distinct value. Using a private member *instead* will make this `int` a per-object property, i.e. there can be objects of type `B` with different `_val` values. And the list goes on. "better" for what?

Comment: @DyP:Thanx, this was the question: What template parameters are better for? What's the point of using them?

Comment: @cpp It's hard to come up with simple examples where non-type parameters *have to* be used. You might know C++11's `std::array` (also in C++03's TR1), which takes a `size_t` for the array size. Non-type template parameters are used quite often in template metaprogramming, as well as for some other rather exotic techniques (e.g. "fast delegates", i.e. function pointer wrappers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `class A` you can only set or modify `val` at compile-time, for `class B` only at run-time. So it depends on when you have enough information to initialize / modify the class. Furthermore, a non-static data member in `class B` adds a per-object state. Instead you could use a `static const int` or an `enum`, which only adds per-class state.

More interestingly, in C++11 you could be using `constexpr` and initalize both at compile-time and at runtime, depending on the context

```
class C {
public:
    constexpr C(int val) : _val(val) {}
    constexpr int the_val() { return _val; }
private:
    int _val;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr C c(5);
    A<c.theval()> a;  // uses constexpr to set template parameter at compile-time
    B b(c.theval());  // can be done at compile-time, but not required ("quality of implementation")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an end result, the assembly code for Class A would be hard coded, and a separate version of the class would exist for all used integers.  A custom class for each constant litteral integer.... in a sense, this is the way to go if you're willing to increase your code size to have execution speed.

Class B constructor would be the same for no matter which integer, and the integer is a run time variable passed in.  One constructor, so code size doesn't increase for each different constant integer you use.